# HTML image not displaying even though the path in the img tag is correct

Tags: html, angular, image

I am trying to display an image in my Angular project using HTML. The code is shown below

```
<img src="../../../../../Uploads/1640665063123--hc-Freeport.jpg" alt="Test">
```

I have verified that the link is correct. The file type is also correct. Additionally, the image has not been corrupted in any way since I can open it in Photos, Visual Studio Code, and Google Chrome. However, the image does not load in HTML. Instead, the "Test" text is shown. Can anyone give me some advice? Am I missing something?

The links below show the structure of my project. The second link shows the file in which the home-page component is located, which is where the image is supposed to be displayed.

https://ibb.co/Qj8HZy5

https://ibb.co/4JSk8g2

Comment: Are you using a relative or full path?

Comment: I am using a relative path

Comment: Can you share the structure of your project?

Comment: I have updated my post with links which show the structure of my project, Rajat. Feel free to check it out if you have time.

Comment: can you try to rename the image name and remove multiple `--`. Try to keep it simple like `abc` for testing purpose if it will work then you can give proper name to it.

Comment: Hey Ambuj, I renamed the image to a simpler name and changed the path. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the image file in assest folder and use this path,

```
<img src="assets/Uploads/1640665063123--hc-Freeport.jpg" alt="Test">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've only just realised that Angular only allows you to read images from the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before when making a website. Try to use the full path from the root or maybe try to use a different text editor or browser.

Comment: I tried the full path as shown below

`<img src="file://E:/Year 4 Semester 1/ECNG 3020/Final_Year_Project/Uploads/1640665063123--hc-Freeport.jpg" alt="Test2">`

Unfortunately, this did not work. It also did not work on different browsers.